# Java Script onClick sends button details when label has no styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a some sample java script which has two buttons `Submit 1` and `Submit 2`. The only difference between these two buttons are the way the label is made. `Submit 1` is inside a `span` tag while the `Submit 2` button is not.

```
<button
    name = {vd.vote_id.toString()}
    id = {vd.vote_id.toString()} 
    poll_id = {vote.poll_id}
    vote_id = {vd.vote_id}
    value = {vd.vote_id}
    className="activePollActionButton"
    onClick={handleSubmitClick}
    type="submit"
>
    <span className="pollActionText"> Submit 1 </span>
</button>

<button 
    name = {vd.vote_id.toString()}
    id = {vd.vote_id.toString()} 
    poll_id = {vote.poll_id}
    vote_id = {vd.vote_id}
    value = {vd.vote_id}
    className="activePollActionButton"
    onClick={handleSubmitClick}
    type="submit"
>
    Submit 2
</button>
```

The handleSubmitClick method, simply prints the event details.

```
const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
};
```

When I click `Submit 1` I could only see the `span` getting printed, while `Submit 2` actually prints the details properly.

```
Submit 1
[Log] <span class="pollActionText"> Submit 1 </span> (bundle.js, line 1461)

Submit 2
[Log] <button name="1" id="1" poll_id="1" vote_id="1" value="1" class="activePollActionButton" type="submit">Submit 2</button> (bundle.js, line 1461)
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Why must you have a span in your `<button>` tag?  Can you not control the content of the button with CSS on `activePollActionButton` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the button element instead of the span when the button is clicked, you can use `e.currentTarget`. The `currentTarget` of the event will always refer to the element to which the event handler has been attached, whereas `target` refers to the element where the event occurred, which could be a child element.

```
 function handleSubmitClick(e){
      console.log(e.currentTarget)
 }
```